# How can i loop through xml element string that ends with a comma and display it on webpage using c#?

Tags: c#, xml

I have the element in my xml,i want to display every string that ends with comma and show something like this and display them in a html table :
ABS
airbag bestuurder
airbag passagier
etc.
I'm using the StringBuilder to show on webpage

```
<opties>
ABS, airbag bestuurder, airbag passagier, airbags hoofd, airbags zij, airbags zij achter, alarm met afstandsbediening, alarmsysteem klasse III, APK, bandenspanning controle syst., centrale vergrendeling, ESP, gordelspanners, lichtsensor, luchtvering, mistlampen voor, parkdistance control achter, parkdistance control voor, regensensor, spiegels verwarmd, startonderbreker, traction control, xenon verlichting, airconditioning, armsteun achter, armsteun voor, automaat, boordcomputer, buitentemperatuur meter, climate control, cruise control, elek. ramen voor + achter, elek. verstelbare voorstoelen, hoofdsteunen achter, houtinleg, in hoogte verstelb. stoel(en), in hoogte verstelbaar stuur, lederen bekleding, lendesteun, multifunctioneel stuurwiel, spiegels elektrisch, stoelverwarming voor, stuurbekrachtiging, tiptronic, bluetooth, carkit, cd-wisselaar, navigatiesysteem, radio/cd-speler, bumpers in carrosseriekleur, getint glas, lichtmetalen velgen, niveauregeling, sportonderstel, vierwielaandrijving (4x4), warmtewerend glas, automatisch dimmende binnenspiegel, dealer onderhouden, incl boekjes, nationale autopas, nieuwstaat, onderhoudsboekjes aanwezig, rokersvrij, zeer mooie en complete limousine
</opties>
```

Comment: Where's your problem?

Comment: Please show the code that you have written to solve this problem. Please also show the output from your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        // create xml document
        var xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
        // load file
        xmldoc.Load(fullpath);            

        // get all elemtents with name option
        var optionNodes = xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("option");

        // create tabel
        StringBuilder resultHtml  = new StringBuilder("<tabel>");

        // loop all option nodes
        foreach (XmlNode node in optionNodes) { 
            // split current node where ,
            string[] words = node.Value.Split(',');
            // loop words and add them to a row
            resultHtml.Append("<tr>");
            foreach (string word in words)
            {
                resultHtml.Append( $"<td>{word}</td>");
            }
            resultHtml.Append("</tr>");
        }
        // close tabel
        resultHtml.Append("</tabel>");
```

Comment: but can't i just the fetch the element <opties>..</opties> and continue from there rather than creating a string s = "ABS,..." ?

Comment: because i've got many of the element <opties>...</opties> in my xml

Comment: Yes you can, wait a sec

Comment: Your welkome : )

Answer (score 1):

You can just replace comma with a break like this

```
"<tr><td>"+Mystring.Replace(",","</td></tr><tr><td>")+"</tr></td>";
```

Trim extras if needed

Comment: but i want to display them in a html table with rows and column so i don't think it would be possible with only <br/>

Comment: @GabrielTakyie you want each of them to be in a single row and cell like <tr><td>text</td></tr>

Answer (score 0):

Split your string into an array (assumption is it's an aspx form):

```
<% string[] arr = sb.ToString().TrimEnd(',').split(',');
foreach(string s in arr){%>
    <tr>
        <td><%= s %></td>
    </tr> 
<% } %>
```